# Unreal Engine 4 fatal error C1083

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've tried to generate a new UE4 Project (C++/Third Person) but I always get the following error

```
The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio?

Running C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.17/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe AnotherWorld Development Win64 -project="C:/Users/Paul/Documents/Unreal Projects/AnotherWorld/AnotherWorld.uproject" -editorrecompile -progress -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Creating makefile for AnotherWorld (no existing makefile)
Performing full C++ include scan (no include cache file)
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for AnotherWorldEditor
Running UnrealHeaderTool "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Unreal  Projects\AnotherWorld\AnotherWorld.uproject" "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Unreal Projects\AnotherWorld\Intermediate\Build\Win64\AnotherWorldEditor\Development\AnotherWorldEditor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Reflection code generated for AnotherWorldEditor in 18,9575823 seconds
@progress pop
Performing 11 actions (2 in parallel)
[2/11] Resource ModuleVersionResource.rc.inl
[3/11] Resource PCLaunch.rc
SharedPCH.Engine.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\INCLUDE\cstddef(5): fatal error C1083: file (Include) could not be opened: "stddef.h": No such file or directory
ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Unreal  Projects\AnotherWorld\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-AnotherWorld.dll
Total build time: 42,13 seconds (Local executor: 0,00 seconds)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Which Versions of Unreal and Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using Unreal Engine 4.17.1 and Visual Studio Community 2017 15.3.4

Comment: I think you are missing the C++ tools in VS2017.

Comment: I've installed the "Game development with C++" workload, so I think the C++ tools should be included.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd toss in my answer for anyone who stumbles across it.

You might be experiencing the same issue I had, that is, I was [missing the UCRT SDK.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24354/cant-compile-vs2015-project-in-vs2017-missing-c-in.html) When you are Modifying your VS install from the Visual Studio Installer, be sure you install the Windows Universal CRT SDK along with which ever version of Windows SDK you are using. In my case, I only had Windows 8.1 SDK component and was receiving the same error.

Once you have the Windows Universal CRT SDK installed, try making a new project with the same settings. Your old projects will not build for what I assume is a problem with the solution properties not including the new ucrt include path.